# Using Multiple model in a single view ASP.NET, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am devolaping a 2nd hand item selling like OLX, I have two models

> 1: Product_model
>
> 2: Customer_model

so i want to use the the product description and customer information in a single view.
Models:

```
 [Table("Product")]
    public class ProductModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
        public string ProductAddress { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage1 { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage2 { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage3 { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
       // public DateTime ProductSubTime { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Customer")]
    public class CustomerModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Customer ID", 
        public string CustomerFullName { get; set; }
        public int CustomerContact { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string CustomerGender { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(cm.Products.ToList());
    }
```

My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.ProductModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyTemplate.cshtml";
}

 <div class="col-md-4"style="border: 2px solid yellow" >
                <div class="single-product-widget" style="border: 2px solid black">
                    <h2 class="product-wid-title">Recently Viewed</h2>
                    <a href="#" class="wid-view-more">View All</a>
                    @{ int i = 0;}
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                           <div class="single-wid-product" style="border: 2px dashed black">
                           <a href="single-product.html"><img src="~/images/@item.ProductImage1" alt="No Photo" class="product-thumb"></a>
                           <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ProductName)</h2>
                           </div>
                    }
             <div>
</div>
```

For understanding purpose i deleted some part of view.
**Please guide me accessing both models in particular view.**
I tried also some methods but not able to get it.
**Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view model with 2 properties like following code

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyModel
        {
            Products = cm.Products.ToList(),
            Customers = cm.Customers.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

In Veiw

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
   @*Write your razor code here*@
}
```

Comment: Thnks!! can you please send me the coding for view, accessing both model using  `@foreach loop()`

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: foreach (var item in Model.Products)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to access several models in a particular view. I assume that you just want to show some customer information in page corner or something. Your layout view may have a requirement to include this customer info (but it does not matter anyway).

1. Most preferable option from my point of view is to use **child action**.

Create `CustomerController`

```
public class CustomerController : Controller {
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ViewResult CustomerInfo() {
        CustomerModel customer = ...
        return PartialView("_CustomerPartial", customer);
    }
}
```

.chstml view will have `@Html.Action("CustomerInfo", "Customer")` where you want customer info to be displayed.

This way you will have a separate `CustomerModel` creation logic.

2. Another option is to use `ViewData` or `ViewBag` to store secondary model information like customer info.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var products = cm.Products.ToList();
    ViewBag.Customer = ... // get customer
    return View(products);
}
```

View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.ProductModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MyTemplate.cshtml";
    var customer = (CustomerModel)ViewBag.Customer;
}

@* display customer info *@
@* either { *@
    <div>Welcome @customer.CustomerFullName. You email is @customer.CustomerEmail</div>   
@* } or { *@
    @Html.Partial("_CustomerPartial", customer)
@* } *@

@foreach(var product in Model) {
    @* display product info *@
}
```

3. Previous option can be changed in a way to use strongly typed model. It is also can be known as **view model** - usually a class that exists only to store necessary info for the view. In your case these are some customer and products information.

ViewModel:

```
public class ProductListViewModel {
    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
}
```